# Role of と in a particular sentence 満たされないと泣いているのは

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, particle-と

Here is a sentence that I have trouble translating

> 満たされないと泣いているのはきっと満たされたいと願うから。

because I have difficulty understanding the role of the と located in the first part of it

> 満たされない**と**泣いているのは ...

The only reason I can think of for using the と is that it is there to indicate a condition. And if indeed と can be used for the conditional, it seems to me that for that, the sentence in the conditional must indicate something always true (obvious). However, at first glance this does not appear to be the case to me. So if I could have some clarification, that would be perfect!

Oh and sorry if my English isn't the most fantastic, it's not my everyday language.

Comment: いい曲ですね。そらるさんの「歌ってみた」を聞いてみたらいかがですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is a quotative と.

> why I'm crying that I feel empty

I think this question is along the line with:

- [と in the first sentence + た in the second sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69812/7810)
- [Function of と in Xと人気になる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68147/7810)
- [What does からと mean in this passage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62406/7810)
- [What does 入らなくなるからと mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46684/7810)
- [Can 気づく be used with quotation と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41946/7810)
- [Use of quote marker と before unusual verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24583/7810)

I do think "quotative" is as problematic a name as "past participle", because what it actually does is letting a verbalized idea embedded as an adverb (that describes cause, aim, manner, background, concurrent action..., and of course, emotion) in a sentence.

Comment: あっごめん気づかなくて閉めちゃった

Comment: @Chocolate ぴえん

Comment: Can we really use と as being quotative when the verb to cry has no connection with verbs such as write, read, look, say, speak, ... (the most common verbs used for this use of と) ?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me and to leave additional links, it's nice.

Comment: @user39946 Yes, this is very commonplace as you can see in the links. "Quotative" is but a label given to a certain usage of it. "Past participle" isn't for the past tense, is it?

Comment: ok but, when I'm doing a basic traduction it seems saying "The reason why I'm crying about being unsatisfied, is because I wish fulfillment." Maybe it's my translation that's preventing me from really understanding that it's quotative. However, I really have a hard time imagining it because I can see another translation "If I'm not satisfied, I'm crying because I want to be satisfied. And it looks a lot more like conditional, but at the same time gives the feeling that we miss the message that the singer wants to convey.

Comment: @user39946 The conditional と would be ungrammatical here. (1) It describes the moment of triggering, so no progressive. (2) "Something + と + an action at your disposal" is prohibited, as it is for unexpected or automatic consequence.

Comment: Oooh I understand now, thank you very much, have a good day

Answer (score 0):

と can be translated as "once, when" and is used in sentences like:
暖かくなると、桜の花が咲きます。(When it gets warm, cherry blossoms come into bloom.)

BUT! Wrong sentence: 春になると、山に遊びに行きましょう。(When spring comes, let's go play in the mountains.) It's wrong, because speaker's volition or request does not follow と.

BUT! Exception - speaker's volitional actions can be used for HABITUAL actions. Example: 私はおなかがすくと、いつもラーメンを作って食べます。(When I am hungry, I always make and eat ramen.)

So, in your case: 満たされないと- when/if speaker is not satisfied - 泣いている - he is [usually/always/used to/...habitual] crying.

And second part: ...のは - and this is what speaker is doing (crying) - きっと満たされたいと願うから。- because he certainly/100% wants to be satisfied.

Comment: The 'と' in the asker's question sounds like the quotative 'と' to me, not the conditional 'と'.

Comment: Isn't it strange to use the conditional in this particular sentence? Unless even if this particle is assimilated to an if / when the general meaning has the possibility of being formulated quite differently. Oh and thank you for your answer, you allowed me to understand a little more the conditional with と by the way.